# MenuInflater can't find Menu Resource Directory

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

[image]

Hi, I am new to Android development. I am facing a problem right now when I write `inflater.inflate(R.menu.dropdown,menu);`  inside `public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` `@Override` method `inflater` can't find `Menu Resource Directory` ( As you see in the picture)

After writing `inflater.inflate(R.` It shows me other options like `id, mipmap,` etc but it can't show the `menu` option. If I press `Alt+Enter` it shows `Create menu resource file 'dropdown.xml'` but `dropdown.xml` already exists in the `Menu Resource Directory`

Does anybody know how to solve this problem

Comment: you may try [file -> Invalidate caches / restart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Restart you `Android studio`.....thats all
```

Actually, sometimes `Android Studio` shows unexpected behaviour, in future, you will face a lot of such problems so it's better to `Restart` whenever you face such unexpected problems.